# Custom control right to left layout

Tags: c#, winforms

I have downloaded custom `ListView` control which does not contain property  for right to left layout.
I wrote this code:

```
public class CustomListView : SourceListView
{
    const int WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = 0x400000;
    const int WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT = 0x100000;
    private bool rightToLeftLayout = false;


    public CustomListView() : base()
    {
        //SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

    }

    [Localizable(true)]
    public bool RightToLeftLayout
    {
        get { return rightToLeftLayout; }
        set
        {
            if (rightToLeftLayout != value)
            {
                rightToLeftLayout = value;
                this.RecreateHandle();
            }
        }
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams CP;
            CP = base.CreateParams;
            if (this.RightToLeftLayout &&
                this.RightToLeft == System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes)
                CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle | WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL | WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT;
            return CP;
        }
    }
```

It flips the `ListView` horizontaly instead of drawing text right to left.
Example here:

[image]

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: How "custom" is this?  Looks like it is using OwnerDraw = True if this is the result.  The Graphics object passed to the DrawColumnHeader event handler will be initialized with ScaleTransform(-1, 1) and that's what text will look like, dutifully backwards.  You'll have to fix that by using the correct ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform.